# Is Gravity force acting upon object inversely propositional to distance between planet and object?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

If I had a building of thousands of km in height. Will I experience less weight and gravity in top floor compered to ground?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will. The gravitational force is proportional to the inverse-square of the distance between you and the planet's center.

Answer (score 0):

> If I climb a building of thousands of kilometers in height, will I experience less weight and gravity on the top floor compared to the ground?

$$\mathbf F_{\text{gravity}}=-\frac{GMm}{r^2}\mathbf{\hat r}$$
Since $G$ and $M$ and your mass $m$ are constants, the force depends only on your distance from the center of the planet. As you go far off into interstellar space, the force experienced decreases.